# How can i save Keras predicted values?

Tags: pandas, csv, keras, save, prediction

i want to save the predicted steering angle values from keras model in csv or txt file.

I want to use it for drawing line graph. I tried to draw without saving values but it looked complicated.

I used pandas to saving values but i got an error message.

I wrote:

```
degrees = float(model.predict(image, batch_size=1))
degrees = pd.DataFrame(degrees, columns=['pred1']).to_csv('data1.csv')
```

and i got this message.

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

How can i save the predicted values properly?

Comment: What does `degrees` look like? Is it a list?

Comment: it looks like you're using `sklearn`, can you show us the rest of your code?

Comment: @SCool it's a steering value which is predicted in realtime. It is predicted like every 0.x seconds and i wanna save these values in a CSV or TXT file in order to make line graph

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your question, your model is returning a single value which you are converting into `float`. Pandas dataframe are basically tables having more than one column. Since `degrees` variable is a single value, you should use Pandas Series here. This should work:

```
degrees = float(model.predict(image, batch_size=1))
degrees = pd.Series(degrees).to_csv('data1.csv', header='pred1')
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. i added pd.series in while loop right after prediction of degrees. but it saved only first 1value and no more.